# How to remove double spaces in between texts on html text input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out, that how to remove the double spaces which are placed in-between texts in the HTML Text field. 
[For example: Tom  and Jerry - in here, after "Tom" there are two spaces are placed]. 
I need to remove or replace the double spaces and place a single space only while keying in the HTML text box. Any Help on this? ... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might add a `keyup` listener, which, when triggered, uses a regular expression to `replace` all double-spaces (or more) with single spaces:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
});
```

```html
<input>
```